# how to add right border before icon in button

Tags: html, css

I want to add a border in the button before the icon
what I m using is that
my code is this

```css
.button {
            background-color: #4CAF50;
            border: none;
            color: white;
            Width: 660px;
            Height:55px;
            padding: 15px 32px;
            text-align: center;
            text-decoration: none;
            display: inline-block;
            font-size: 16px;
            margin: 4px 2px;
            cursor: pointer;
            background: #333333;
            position: absolute;
            left: 16.76%;
            right: 16.68%;
            top: 27.29%;
            bottom: 30.89%;
            font-family: DIN Pro;
            font-style: normal;
            font-weight: bold;
            font-size: 18px;
            line-height: 23px;
            text-align: center;
            text-transform: uppercase;
            color: #F6F6F6;
        }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
    </head>
    <body>
        <a href="#" class="button">Contact<span style="border:solid 1px white"><i class="fa fa-home;"></span></i></a>
    </body>
</html>
```

but it is not setting up like that. I want to set it up like the same is in the picture

[image: Image Link]

Comment: Please visit the [help], take the [tour] to see what and [ask]. Do some research, search for related topics on SO; if you get stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output using the `[<>]` snippet editor.

Comment: @mplungjan please check the question again i update it

Comment: You just pasted some code. I clicked edit, then `[<>]` and filled in the proper panes. Your code shows a house, the image an arrow. What is it you want? CanI click contact, should I click the house or an arrow? What?

Comment: @mplungjan i add a image if u see it. i want to make the button same like image. the button have a border before the icon i want to setup like that. i try it but i can't add it. that's why i posted

Comment: maybe starting to set the icone behind the text ? `<a href="#" class="button">Contact <i class="fa fa-arrow-right"></i></a>` and use the right class name for the arrow ? then clarify, is it only the arrow that is clickable or the whole link ?

Comment: @G-Cyrillus how i can border before the icon. ther is a border 1px white

Comment: `border:solid 1px white`. you just said it!

Comment: @G-Cyrillus it is not adjusting like i want

Comment: Did you modify your HTML ? , did you manage to send the icon to the far right ? , where did you add that border ? ... Your code sample is far looking like the screen you added. It's not only a border matter here. Clarify ;)

Comment: @G-Cyrillus <a href="#" class="button">Contact<span style="border:solid 1px white"><i class="fa fa-home;"></span></i></a>
i set up like that

Comment: update your snippet, so everybody sees it ;)

Comment: @G-Cyrillus i update it but can u please tell me how i make the button same like image

Comment: You maybe should give up  the absolute positionning untill you manage display (for layout) . here an example via flex : https://jsfiddle.net/kue4sw9c/  - https://jsfiddle.net/kue4sw9c/2/

Comment: Also you have two  color statements

Comment: @G-Cyrillus thank u that thing i needed

Answer (score 1):

Here is the code you need for the button. To answer your question about the border on the icon, I added a [pseudo element](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_pseudo_elements.asp) (`:after`) to the button which contains the arrow icon. Then it was just a matter of applying `border-left` to it.

```css
/* button styles */

.button {
  background-color: slategray;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  min-height: 42px;
  min-width: 180px;
  max-width: 100%;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-decoration: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  font-size: 18px;
  text-align: center;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  color: #F6F6F6;
  display: inline-flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  padding: 8px 52px 8px 10px;
  position: relative;
}

.button:after {
  content: "\f061";
  display: flex;
  position: absolute;
  font-family: "Font Awesome 5 Free", sans-serif;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 42px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  text-align: center;
  border-left: 1px solid #8192a2;
}

.button:hover {
  background-color: #8192a2;
}

.button:hover:after {
  border-left-color: #95a7b8;
}


/* example styles */

body,
html {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  background: coral;
}

* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.15.2/css/all.min.css">


<a href="#" class="button">Contact</a>
```